# Asterisk ARI Bridge Record to Separate Files/Channels

Tags: asterisk

I'm wondering if anyone has any experience recording an ARI bridge to separate files, unmixed (or at least to separate L and R channels of a stereo file). It seems this can be achieved by recording separate Channels but then these channels are not able to be bridged.

Recording two bridged channels always results in a mixed audio file.

I'd appreciate it if anyone could point me in the direction of successfully recording the In and Out channels of a bridge discretely, similar to the Monitor dial plan application. Or even bridging two channels that are already being independently recorded.

Are there any workaround for this that I'm not seeing?

I know I can get there without ARI but I'd love to use ARI. It can do everything I'd need it to do but this.

Thanks!

Comment: That's an interesting question. I am just curious to get an understanding of your usage situation.

Answer (score 0):

Application Monitor not mix channel.

Application MixMonitor do mix, but create stereo.

You can transfer you call to dialplan which do Mix/Monitor after that bridge it back via ARI.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, what you have to do is create a seperate spy channel attached to each participant in the bridge. Then you can record the spy channel. And you can set the Spy to only monitor the direction you want. Then you would need to manually mix the calls down yourself afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Waking up an old post.
If you want to have ‘stereo’ recordings, i.e. channel A on the left and channel B on the right...

All you need to do is Record channel A and B separately and combine them after a call using a tool like SoX

Normal dialplan MixMonitor is the equivalent of recording a bridge with ARI
Normal dialplan Monitor is the equivalent of recording  channel with ARI.